# next.js 404 fail to load resource /api/ on vercel

Tags: api, next.js, http-status-code-404, vercel

i'm building a next js website that i deploy on vercel.

I made a next.js api /api/contact which send a mail via nodemailer. It works fine when i try the code on my pc but when i upload on vercel (with github integration) i get a "404 failed to load resource" for /api/contact in the console and it doesn't work.

Is there any more configuration to do for next.js api to work on vercel ?

Here is the code for the api call :

```
fetch("/api/contact", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then((res) => {
```

[contact.js in api folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYDpy.png)

Comment: Where are you making the API call from?

Comment: So for now i just have one page (index.js) which is in the pages folder, i'm making the call from here after clicking on a button : onClick={handleSubmit}
`const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("/api/contact" ...`

Answer (score 0):

So here are the answers that worked :
"failed to load resource" disappeared after several deployments but i still had a 404.
Problem was that transporter.sendMail needed to be async + i  had issue with gmail, i ended using another mail provider (zoho). So for anyone faceing the same issues here is a working code (maybe not the best but it's working) :

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
  require('dotenv').config()
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

  async function mail() {
    console.log('enter async function');
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      name: "smtp.zoho.com",
      port: 465,
      host: "smtp.zoho.com",
      auth: {
        user: process.env.mailsender,
        pass: process.env.mailpw,
      },
      secure: true,
    })
    let mail = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: process.env.mailsender,
      to: process.env.mailreceive,
      subject: `${req.body.message}`,
      text: `${req.body.message}`,
      html: `<div><p>${req.body.message}</p></div>`
    });
  }

  try {
    console.log('sending mail');
    await mail();
    res.status(200);
    console.log('mail should be sent');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log('error sending mail');
    res.status(404);
  } finally {
    res.end();
  };
}
```